# Import module not in Webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

For my current project, I'm developing a frontend application that consumes a backend API. I would like to keep the URL of the backend dynamic (e.g. in a seperate config file). However, with Webpack, all defined variables end up in a bundle, which makes it hard to keep the backend URL dynamic (I'd have to dive in the bundle and change the URL).

How would I achieve this using Webpack 2? Basically I want to import a config file that gets excluded from the bundle so I can easily modify the config file later on.

My current solution is to define a window.config object in my index.html and read the window object from my application. I feel there should be a better way to achieve this though.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you modify the config file, why doesn't webpack watch for changes and update the bundle file accordingly?

Comment: It does, however I want to be able pick up the bundle, use it somewhere else and change the config file without updating the bundle.